# Ability to edit local copies of remote branches

Tags: git

I have difficulty understanding/verifying the following line from [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches):

> It’s important to note that when you do a fetch that brings down new
> remote-tracking branches, you don’t automatically have local, editable
> copies of them. In other words, in this case, you don’t have a new
> serverfix branch — you have only an origin/serverfix pointer that you
> can’t modify.

I tried the following for a repository.

```
git clone git://git.bugseng.com/ppl/ppl.git
cd ppl
```

I removed folder `ppl/src/` from my local machine, and made a copy of pre-existing folder `ppl/m4/` into `ppl/m4 - Copy` just so as to locally modify/edit this folder a bit.

Then, I ran `git fetch origin` just to (I thought) set myself up to be in the situation mentioned in the book's quote above. I (of course) do not have any *write* access to this online repository.

Now, I am easily able to do `git add .` and `git commit` without any errors. Output of `git status` is:

```
:~/ppl$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

all as expected. That is, I have been able to make a commit and edit the branch *locally*. I am unable to reconcile this with the quote from the book which states that I would not have local editable copies of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the phrases you quoted refer to a `serverfix` branch — not to `master`.

In the case of `master` (or whatever the remote HEAD is), when you clone you are given a local copy automatically; thus there was no need for you to make one.

But if there had been any *other* branches, `clone` does not make local copies of those for you, and a mere `fetch` would not have given you local copies of them either. You might have remote-tracking branches such as `origin/someBranch`, but if you wanted to *edit* `someBranch`, you'd have to create it first.

Comment: This is clarifying, thanks. The book does state the following (which makes sense now after your answer because it is not `master`, one has to do the following extra)
`$ git checkout -b serverfix origin/serverfix`
This extra work is not needed if one just `clones` since we are already on `master` locally.

Comment: And there are shortcuts. On my machine, if there is a remote-tracking `origin/serverfix` but no local `serverfix`, merely saying `git switch serverfix` will _create_ the local branch. Thus, `git switch serverfix` appears to work always, as _if_ there had been a local branch all along, but in fact there wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

The Pro Git reference is saying that a `git fetch` does not actually checkout a local copy of the remote branch you have fetched. It is merely a pointer to allow git locally to know the branch exists and allow you to check it out. To test this, clone a copy of your remote repository. Next create a branch on your remote `fetch-branch-test`. Run `git checkout fetch-branch-test` on your local repo, and you will get an error saying git can't find the branch. Run `git fetch` locally, then `git branch`. You will see that there is still no local copy of `fetch-branch-test`. Finally, run `git checkout fetch-branch-test` again, and you will notice you now have a local copy of the remote branch. This is because git fetch added a local pointer of the new remote branch, but did not add a local copy of it until you ran `git checkout`.

Comment: Yes, this is a test that can help me verify it for myself. All of the editing/modifying I have been able to do in the OP has been on `master` that is a local version of remote tracking `origin/master` that is automatically checked out on a clone.